# Pre-load MS Windows right-click menus and Start menu at startup

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, right-click

On my WinXP SP3 laptop (1.4Ghz 1.2GB ram), after I first log in, when I right-click in Windows Explorer and choose New, the submenu can take up to 15 seconds to load, which is a pain in the ass when you want to do a quick easy operation.

After the submenu has loaded the first time, subsequent loads perform instantly, obviously as the menu has been cached.

My question is: can these right-click menus (and the Start menu, which also takes some time to load the first time) be pre-loaded at Windows startup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any custom entries in that particular right click menu? Software installs sometimes put in custom entries, these can cause a slow load of the context menu.

You can use this software to remove any custom entries that you suspect are causing the slow down, default windows entries do not cause this issue, only custom ones added by 3rd party software installs.

http://www.sdsoftware.org/default.asp?id=11403

Comment: Why do 3rd party entries take so much longer than default entries?  Aren't they all listed in the same place?

Comment: because the 3rd party software is poorly coded.